# How to upload file using nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am lost on how to upload a file using nodejs. First time doing it. I have followed many 'guides' and none have worked. I try to format the code to fit with what I am doing and it fails. I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction or help.

My code I have now is below.

```
startup.js model file

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var startupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    about_startup: {
        startup_name: String,
        startup_url: String,
        short_description: String,
        long_description: String,
        tech_stack: String,
        date_founded: Date,
        image: //what do I put here?
    },
    social_media: {
        blog: String,
        twitter: String,
        facebook: String,
        linkedin: String,
        email: String,
    },
    about_founder: {
        founder_name: String,
        social_media_founder: String
    }
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("Startup", startupSchema);
```

Then my route is:

```
app.js

// CREATE add new startup to database
router.post("/new", function(req, res) {
   // Get data from form
   var about_startup = {
       startup_name: req.body.startupname,
       startup_url: req.body.url,
       short_description: req.body.shortdescription,
       long_description: req.body.longdescription,
       tech_stack: req.body.techstack,
       date_founded: req.body.foundeddate,

   };
   var social_media = {
       blog: req.body.blog,
       twitter: req.body.twitter,
       facebook: req.body.facebook,
       linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
       email: req.body.email
   };
   var about_founder = {
        founder_name: req.body.foundername,
        social_media_founder: req.body.foundersocialmedia
   };

   //Pass data through | Write better explaination later
   var newStartup = {about_startup: about_startup, social_media: social_media, about_founder: about_founder};
   Startup.create(newStartup, function(err, newlyCreatedStartup){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           // Redirect back to show all page
           res.redirect("/startups");
       }
   });
});
```

This code works for what I want other than to upload the file. The html input for the image/file upload is:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> image: //what do I put here?
> ```

You can use **String**

> Why **String**?

- You can convert an image to a base64 string with ease
- The string can be used to render the image in html
- The string can be re-converted to a file

[JSFiddle : Convert an image to a **base64 string**](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)